# How to create an EventSourceMapping with serverless 1.0?

Tags: lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to set up an event source map so the Lambda Function gets call every time a record gets committed into my dynamodb table. I am trying to follow up the instructions from

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/docs/guide/overview-of-event-sources.md

My current `serverless.yml` is using:

```
service: sl-pipeline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  memorySize: ${memoryVar}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "dynamodb:*"
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/MyTable*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "dynamodb:GetRecords"
        - "dynamodb:GetShardIterator"
        - "dynamodb:DescribeStream"
        - "dynamodb:ListStreams"
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/MyTable*/stream/*"

# you can overwrite defaults here
defaults:
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  main:
    handler: handler.main

# Add event trigger from dynamodb Stream Table
resources:
  Resources:
    mapping:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
      Properties:
        BatchSize: 10
        EventSourceArn: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXX:table/MyTable/stream"
        FunctionName: "sl-pipeline-dev-main"
        StartingPosition: LATEST
```

And every time I call `serverless deploy`, I get:

```
 Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

 An error occurred while provisioning your cloudformation:
 The following resource(s) failed to create: [IamRoleLambda,
 mapping].
```

I am guessing this has to do with IAM role permissions, but cannot figure out how to fix it. For the role I use for serverless itself, I have tried to just use:

```
Action: "*"
Resource: "*"
```

so it should be able to do anything.

Note that if I remove the `resources` section from the `serverless.yml`, I can deploy correctly. I can even go to the dynamodb table, and manually add the trigger to the lambda function and it all works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First off; see why the IamRoleLambda cannot be created. Go to AWS web console and go to CloudFormation. Click on your stack (probably it says it is failed). Scroll to the failed step and see why. It usually specify exactly what failed.

Second; you do not need your lambda execution role to have permissions to the stream. Try to remove the part from the iam policy about the stream. So it looks like this instead:

```
provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: python2.7
    memorySize: ${memoryVar}
    iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
         - "dynamodb:*"
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/MyTable*"
```